# gradient drawable not working

Tags: android, drawable

I am trying to create a gradient that goes from the centre outwards. (or inwards). So the outside is the same color, and as you get closer to center, it turns red or something.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    >

    <gradient 
          android:startColor="#ffffff"
            android:endColor="#ff00ff00"
            android:centerX="50%"
            android:centerY="50%"
            android:gradientRadius="50%"
            android:type="radial"
        />
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it this way

```
    <gradient android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="50"
    android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:endColor="#ff00ff00" />
```

Basically try without the percentage on gradientRadius

Comment: Thanks. :) `gradientRadius` appears to be the pixel distance from the center, where it starts changing colour. So I set it to 1000 to make the whole screen be gradient :) (with 50, its just a small circle thats gradient)